# Intercepting pan gestures over a UIScrollView breaks scrolling

Tags: ios, ios5, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a vertically-scrolling `UIScrollView`. I want to also handle horizontal pans on it, while allowing the default vertical scroll behavior. I've put a transparent `UIView` over the scroll view, and added a pan gesture recognizer to it. This way I can get the pans just fine, but then the scroll view doesn't receive any gestures.

I've implemented the following `UIPanGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods, hoping to limit my gesture recognizer to horizontal pans only, but that didn't help:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // Only accept horizontal pans here.
    // Leave the vertical pans for scrolling the content.
    CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
    BOOL isHorizontalPan = (fabsf(translation.x) > fabsf(translation.y));
    return  isHorizontalPan;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return (otherGestureRecognizer == _scrollView.panGestureRecognizer);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `[panGesture setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];`? Simply returning YES in `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` might help you figure out where the problem is as well.

Comment: Just tried it, no difference.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. I needed to do 2 things to make this work:

1) Attach my own pan recognizer to the scroll view itself, not to another view on top of it.

2) This `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method prevents the goofy behavior that happens when both the default scrollview and my own one are invoked simultaneously.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: the default behavior of shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer is to return NO, so that add is unneeded

Comment: change the return value to `YES` and it works great.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem to solve and I did this:

1) Attach my own pan recognizer to the scroll view.

2) Return YES on:
– gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:

This will allow both gestures to work. So what that means is that on vertical scroll, both your panGesture delegate and scrollView Delegate will be fired. If it is a horizontal scroll, it will only call your panGesture delegate.

3) in my panGesture delegate, detect if it is a horizontal scroll, if it is not, ignore.

Comment: This is exactly the same that I recommend in my own answer.

Comment: @BlackRider it is not. This returns YES

Comment: Thanks `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` did the trick.

Answer (score 11):

Swift answer:

```
let scrollViewPanGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onPan(_:)))
scrollViewPanGesture.delegate = self
scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(scrollViewPanGesture)

extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it works well, but if we are moving the scrollview by the changed location there will be a shaking while we are scrolling the content.
Hope there is a solution for that case :)

Comment: and can you do me a favor to implement this solution with SWIFTUI?

Answer (score 2):

#### For the very anal programmer:

You don't just willy-nilly return true. You should check if the "other" gesture is indeed the scroll view in question.

That's complicated because scrollviews have MANY gesture recognizers attached.

You can do this to see them all, and how many there are in (current) UIKit as you read this

```
print("count \(primaryScroll.gestureRecognizers?.count)")
print("count \(primaryScroll.gestureRecognizers)")
```

So, the full solution is:

```
import UIKit
class Examp: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    var primaryScroll: UIScrollView ... your scroll view in question

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let p = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panned))
        p.delegate = self
        primaryScroll.addGestureRecognizer(p)
    }
    
    func gestureRecognizer(
     _ g: UIGestureRecognizer,
     shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith other: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

        guard
         let gg = primaryScroll.gestureRecognizers,
         gg.contains(other) else { return false }

        return true
    }

    @objc func panned(p: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let v = p.velocity(in: view).x
        if p.state == .ended && abs(v) > 300 { print("swiped") }
        // etc ...
    }
```

And that's it.

If you don't check that the `other` gesture is in fact the scroll view in question, you'll get an incredibly hard-to-debug issue.