# Scrollview and Side menu with Pan Gesture Conflict

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am designing a App in swift which contains Left Side out Menu.
I had used Navigation Controller for Recognizing Pan depending on which I am toggling Left Side Out menu.

Below is code for attaching pan gesture with navigation controller

```
let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePanGesture:")
    centerNavigationController.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)*
```

In other controllers it is working fine, but in controller where there is Scroll view I want that after scroll view is scrolled till content offset 0 and further scrolled on left side it should open up left side out menu.
but it prevents calling pan gesture.

It is conflicting.

I have tried number of solutions using method

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {}
```

But it didn't worked.

Please let me know if any additional info required for defining problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the solution to this issue [in this thread.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13736630/2740582)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

Use SwrevealviewController ,you will get all those things

Comment: Thanks Abdul for your answer